# Concatenating 2D array into string causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, string-concatenation, strcat

I'm trying to concatenate a matrix into one long string using `strcat`, but keep getting seg faults whenever I attempt to access the matrix or use `strcat`. The segmentation fault occurs as soon as I enter the function. The first `printf` never executes.

```
void concatMatrix(int **matrix, char *output){ 
  printf("%s", "SDFSDFDSFDSFDSF");

  char *str = "";
  char *temp = "sdds";
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
       // temp = (char)matrix[i][j];
       // strcat(str, temp);
       // strcat(str, ' ');
       // printf("%d\n", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    // strcat(str, "\n");
    strcat(output, str);
    // printf("%s", output);
  }
}
```

This is how matrix and output were declared, and matrix was filled with values before calling the function.

```
int matrix[5][5];
char output[25];
```

Whenever I try to use matrix or output or `strcpy()` I get a segmentation fault. I can use `printf` simply on str or temp, but that is all. All the lines commented out will cause a seg fault. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you pass the variable declared like this: `int matrix[5][5];` to a function, it decays to a *single* pointer (`int*`) ***not*** an `int**`. It will point to the start of the block of data that is 'perceived' by the program as a 1D array of 25 integers.

Comment: Ref your commented-out `// strcat(str, temp);` you can't do that with a *string literal*. Apart from `*str` pointing to a 1-byte space, it is read-only.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest complete code that shows the problem.

Comment: Please add `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` debugging cue, to be sure it is printed. When a program crashes, buffred output is usually discarded. Back to my earlier comment, you can try `char str[1024] = "";` instead, or longer, and guarded from overflow by using `strncat`.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! changing my string to not read-only fixed a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is of type `int (*)[5]` and the parameter is of type `int**`, these are not compatible, use:

```
void concatMatrix(int matrix[][5], char *output);
```

Furthermore, `strcat`'s second parameter is expecting a char array and you are passing single char arguments to it, aside from the fact that `str` points to a string literal which is constant and cannot be altered.

You wouldn't need to use `strcat` to do this, you can assign these directly to `output` with a proper conversion:

[Running sample](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/StupendousPeacefulLevel)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void concatMatrix(int matrix[][5], char *output)
{  
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++, index++)
        {        
        output[index] =  matrix[i][j] + '0'; //convert from int to char and assign to output
        }       
    }
    output[index] = '\0'; //null terminate the string
}

int main()
{
    int matrix[5][5] = {{1, 4, 3, 5, 2},
                        {7, 9, 5, 9, 0},
                        {1, 4, 3, 5, 2},
                        {1, 4, 3, 5, 2},
                        {7, 9, 5, 9, 0}};
    char output[26]; //must have space for null terminator
    concatMatrix(matrix, output);
    printf("%s", output);
}
```

This will work only for single digits, wich, I gather, is the intended purpose given the size of the `output` string and the rest of the code.